# צִרְעָה Pshat or definition

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, ekev

וְגַם אֶת הַצִּרְעָה יְשַׁלַּח יְ־הֹוָ־ה אֱלֹהֶיךָ בָּם עַד אֲבֹד הַנִּשְׁאָרִים וְהַנִּסְתָּרִים מִפָּנֶיךָ ([Deuteronomy 7:20](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0507.htm#20))

What is the הַצִּרְעָה mean in this posuk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2010/07/what-is-tzirah.html) and the follow-up [here](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2010/08/yet-more-on-tzirah.html). According to Rashi, a sort of insect. According to Ibn Ezra and Ibn Janach, a type of sickness.

Answer (score 6):

While Josh did an excellent job, I'd like to add my two cents based on some research I did on this a few years back...

Also: It's worth reading to the end.  If you have any questions on any of this, please comment below.

---

Rabbi Kaplan, based on Onkelos and others identifies it as follows ([Living Torah Ex. 23:28](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?action=displayanchor&pentid=P2170#C1491)):

> deadly wasps
>
> Some authorities identify the tzir'ah here with the hornet, [Vespa Orientalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriental_hornet), a species that is known to multiply in time of war. It was known as a honey-producing insect (Makh'shirim 6:4), and in Talmudic times, was known to be dangerous (Shabbath 80b; Taanith 14a). Also see Deuteronomy 7:20, Joshua 24:12; Wisdom of Solomon 12:8.

Rashi (as quoted [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67949/16354) in another question) suggets (based on Chazal) that it was some sort of hornet that deposited poison into the eyes of their enemies:

> רש"י - הצרעה – מין שרץ העוף, שהיתה זורקת בהן מרה ומסרסתן ומסמא עיניהם בכל מקום שהיו נסתרו' שם.

Ibn Ezra suggests that it was some sort of sickness:

> ראב"ע - הצרעה – חולי בגוף, מגזרת: צרעת.

Bechor Shor suggests that it is something which pained and minimized those hidden:

> ר"י בכור שור - ...ולפי הפשט נראה: צרעה – צעורה, כמו: שמלה שלמה, כבשים כשבים. כלומר: שיצער וימעיט אותם שנסתרים מפניך...

Ibn Balaam suggests that it may have been a plague of fear over the land:

> ר"י אבן בלעם - וגם {את הצר}עה – מכה מוסתרת מן {מכות} (?) מסויימות. והמאפיין אותה שתהיה מכת הפחד והיא... על כל ארץ ישראל.

Ralbag understands it to be referring to God's help, as if it was coming via hornets:

> רלב"ג - ושלחתי את הצרעה לפניך להזיק לאומות אשר תלחם בהם. והנה אמר זה על דרך משל על העזר האלהי שיהיה נלוה לישראל בהכנעת האומות ההם.

Chizkuni says that according to Peshat, it is a way of saying that Hashem will chase them out by using light means, not heavy ones such as battle:

> חזקוני (שמות, ובדברים כתב כראב"ע) - ושלחתי את הצרעה – פרש"י מין שרץ, והיא לא עברה את הירדן ומה שכתוב וגרשה את החוי ואת הכנעני וגו' אמרינן במסכת סוטה ריש לקיש אמר על שפת הירדן עמדה וזרקה בהם מרה. רב פפא אמר שתי צרעות היו חדא דמשה וחדא דיהושע, דמשה לא עברה ודיהושע עברה. ולפי הפשט משל הוא לא בחרב ולא בקשת אני מגרשם אלא בדבר קל.

Ibn Caspi suggests it is a Mashal and refers to all methods of chasing out (since people normally run away from hornets).

> ר"י אבן כספי - ושלחתי את הצרעה – הוא מין הדבורים היותר רע. ואולי כן היה באחת ממלחמות יהושע או אחריו בימי הזקנים ואם לא נזכר ואולי הוא משל כולל לכל מיני המדיחים והמגרשים.

Ibn Janach says that it is some sort of destructive plague.

> ר"י אבן ג'אנח – כליון ודבר.

Some recent authors, such as Neufeld ([here](https://www.cabdirect.org/cabdirect/abstract/19800210795)), suggest that this was a primitive form of biological warfare using insects.

Other authors/archaeologists, such as Yigael Yadin have taken the view that it refers to the Egyptians, since their symbol was that of a hornet. (See [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=NAGzjl6LF-sC&pg=PT236&lpg=PT236&dq=garstang%20egypt%20hornet&source=bl&ots=E5XjL-MxYu&sig=imj6pQkZsrNyXoLUFTMccIDEJmw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj48q3hiszcAhXB54MKHYEEBb0Q6AEwDHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=garstang%20egypt%20hornet&f=false).)

Comment: Well worth two cents, though if you can locate direct links it would be even better (spec. for Ibn Balaam, Ibn Kaspi & Ibn Janah).

Comment: Ibn Janach was from his Sefer Hashorashim, IIRC.  The other two are at alhatorah.  The alhatorah links are edited in. Ibn Caspi is in Shemos, Ibn Balaam in Devarim.